# php, substr, 'out of memory'

Tags: php, substr

So I have a script that imports CSV files into a contacts table in a database.

I have made a script that will grab a chunk of a CSV and process it, update a queue table with its progress, and then use cron to run that regularly so it can essentially process any size file.

Anyways I have limited it to only run 1000 lines at a time to stop it from falling over. This works very well, but I have had someone try to upload a CSV with a larger amount of fields than usual, which means 1 line of the CSV is much bigger than usual.

When I pass the data to a function to build a query to put it in the database, I am getting an "out of memory" error on a substr() function when it trims the query.

```
$q = substr($q, 0, -1);
```

By this point in the script, $q is getting pretty big, which is what seems to be killing it. Any idea how to chop off the last character without loading the whole var into memory? Other than just making the batch size smaller?

Comment: If the CSV file is not the part of your application functionality you can direct import the data into table by mysql command otherwise increase php `memory_limit`

Comment: Are you gettig *out of memory* when processing a single line? OR are you using a long `insert` query to inert multiple line int the DB?

Comment: yes its part of the functionality, need to check existence of rows and process a few other bits. and i get out of memory when trimming off the end comma from the massive query var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Horse: If you know what the character is going to be, you could try

```
$q = rtrim($q, ","); // if it is a comma, for instance
```

Otherwise you can see if you get the same error with

```
$q = mb_substr($q, 0, -1);
```

or

```
$q = substr_replace($q, "", -1)
```

Comment: hmm, rtrim may do the job, as I just want to strip the comma off the end of a var which is building a mass batch insert query.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the PHP file functions take a `length` parameter which will limit the amount of text the function reads in. Perhaps you can set this to a value longer than your expected input size but shorter than a line length that will give you memory errors.

Otherwise, look carefully at your code and make sure that in your loop you aren't building up any large variables or leaking memory. It's impossible to tell without looking at your code if you have a problem there. But if you keep all variables scoped within the loop, you really shouldn't have memory issues because of a single line. That line would ned to be absolutely huge.

And you can always increase your memory limit of course. That would be the easiest thing to do.

Finally, my experience is that the line reported by a memory limit error is almost never the real culprit. It's just the line where the error happened to occur. The problem is usually earlier in the code and is more algorithmic than anything else. So I wouldn't concentrate too hard on that substr() call. Work on your overall memory usage.

Comment: The var is huge though, as to prevent having to do 1000 seperate insert queries, which takes ages, I have made a single batch query. This var is built up as it loops through all the contacts and values, and just needs to trim the comma off the end

Comment: that said, thanks for the response and I agree that the way I have gone about things have probably caused this. just wondered if there was a more efficient way to do it rather than upping the memory limit (am on a shared server)

Comment: It sounds like it's that large query string. I would run the query every 100-200 iterations of your loop rather than wait until the end. In other words, use a counter to keep track of how many lines you're processed. When `$counter % 100 == 0` run the query and wipe out the built up string. This way you'd run the query ten times, which shouldn't be a performance hit, and decrease the size of that string by 90%

Comment: yup i already have this functionality in place, I just have had to decrease the number in the batch. the question was simply a case of finding out if there was a more efficient way of doing the substr which seems to be the case with rtrim